# Showing $ \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{E}_\theta[X\mid Y]N(\mu,\sigma^2)(d\theta) = \frac{\mu+\sigma^2X}{1+\sigma^2}. $ [In relation to Bandit Problems]

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, bayesian

Suppose that $X,Y \sim N(\theta,1)$ where $\theta$ is an outcome of the prior distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Then I want to verify that
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{E}_\theta[X\mid Y]N(\mu,\sigma^2)(d\theta) = \frac{\mu+\sigma^2X}{1+\sigma^2}.
$$
Can anyone help me? In particular, I am stuck trying to work on $\mathbb{E}_\theta[X\mid Y]$. I have tried writing this out as:
$$
\mathbb{E}_\theta[X\mid Y=y]=\int_\mathbb{R}xf_{X\mid Y}(x \mid y)dx
$$
but this doesn't seem to lead anywhere. I need to use that I know both the marginals distributions for $X$ and $Y$ and that inside the outer integral $\theta$ is fixed.

---

To provide a bit of context, this is from reformulated from an example of strategies in bandit problems in a Reinforcement Learning text book ($X$ and $Y$ being rewards in different rounds). As I am fairly new to the Bayesian point of view, this might be a simple problem but I still struggle quite a bit.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the role of Normal mu sig^2 in the integral? Essentially, what is the integrand?

Comment: It should be understood as integration with respect to the measure that has the pdf of a Gaussian/Normal variable. In other words:
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{E}_\theta[X\mid Y]N(\mu,\sigma^2)(d\theta) = \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{E}_\theta[X\mid Y]\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp(-(\theta-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2) \ d\theta
$$

Comment: How can one answer without knowing the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Thanks a lot, and what is the exact form of the term $E_{\theta}[X|Y]$? This is related to the comment by @StubbornAtom, I guess :-).

Comment: Can you add a link to the source of the problem? Perhaps the expectation you want in the integrand is $E[Y|X]$ ?  or you want $Y$ instead of $X$ on the RHS?